# Typescript never gives any error for array & tuples

Tags: typescript

It never gives any array. Array accept only for one type. but tuples can allow multiple values.

```
var myTuple = [10,"Hello"];
console.log(myTuple[1]);

var myArray:number[] = [10,20,"Hello"];
console.log(myArray[2]);
```

[+] Update : my question, why doesn't it give any run time errors ?

Comment: whats the question? what IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Code , Question updated

Comment: It works fine in the typescript playground (i get the error): seems to be a misconfiguration. You'd have to provide your `tsconfig.json`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAtgngKgVwA4BsCmEC8EDaBGABgBoAiACTRRQHsSBdAbgCgBjagOwGdr0A6GgOYAKWIlRp8dAJTMmoSLACCYMCBgAudgigAjNGBx0suQkQBMxcpRr1mbLjzT9qwpSrU4z0hkA

Comment: It doesn't give any runtime errors, because typescript is *compiletime* only. TS is compiled to javascript, and in javascript there is no such thing as a `myArray: number[]`

Comment: @derpirscher Agreed.   when i run `tsc index.ts` then it gives compile error. when i run `tsc index.ts | node index.js` then it works without having any issues :)

Comment: Yeah, because with `|` you are ignoring the non-zero exit code of `tsc` and executing `node index.js` anyways. If you try `tsc index.ts && node index.js` you'll notice, that the `node` part isn't executed anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is a statically typed language that works compile-time and it eventually converts your code to pure Javascript. the code in your post will be converted to below js code:

```
var myTuple = [10, "Hello"];
console.log(myTuple[1]);
var myArray = [10, 20, "Hello"];   // notice how number[] is stripped away from your code
console.log(myArray[2]);
```

Since Javascript is a dynamically typed language, it has no issues with `myArray`. whereas in Typescript, you have specified before hand that myArray would be a number array type and TS being a statically typed language checks if the value assigned to myArray is indeed a number array or not, which in this case is not. so it raises the following error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
```